# playframework testing scala application returns error

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework

I want to write Tests for my playframework scala application.

My test looks like this:

```
class ProcessInstancesControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification {
  sequential

  "ProcessInstancesController" should {

    def ProcessInstancesController(implicit app: Application) = {
      val app2ProcessInstancesController = Application.instanceCache[controllers.ProcessInstancesController]
      app2ProcessInstancesController(app)
    }

    implicit val projectInstanceFormat = Json.format[ProcessInstancesModel]

    val validProcessInstanceJson = AnyContentAsJson(Json.parse(
      """{
        |   "processTemplateId":47,
        |   "startedAt":"2017-12-19 13:50:24",
        |   "updatedAt":"2017-12-19 13:50:24",
        |   "status":"started",
        |   "comment":"",
        |   "deleted":false,
        |   "clientId":35,
        |   "steps":[
        |      {
        |         "id":62,
        |         "title":"Scala Test",
        |         "createdat":"2017-12-12 11:09:56.0",
        |         "updatedat":"2017-12-12 11:09:56.0",
        |         "deadline":1512946800000,
        |         "stepType":1,
        |         "position":0,
        |         "deleted":false,
        |         "processTemplate_id":47,
        |      }
        |   ]
        |}""".stripMargin))


    val app = GuiceApplicationBuilder().overrides(bind[DeadboltHandler].to[DeadboltHandlerMock])

    "respond to the index Action" in new WithApplication {
      val Some(result) = route(app, FakeRequest(GET, "/processInstanceAll/35"))
      status(result) must equalTo(OK)
      contentType(result) must beSome("text/html")
      charset(result) must beSome("utf-8")
      contentAsString(result)         must contain("[{\"data\":{\"id\":117")
      contentAsString(result)        must contain("processTemplateId")
      contentAsString(result)         must contain("clientId")
//      contentAsString(result) must contain("Hello Bob")
    }
```

When I try to run it I got this error Message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Fatal execution error, caused by play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder$.apply$default$9()Lscala/Option;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder$.apply$default$9()Lscala/Option;
    at play.api.test.WithApplication$.$lessinit$greater$default$1(Specs.scala:36)
    at controllers.ProcessInstancesControllerSpec$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2$$anon$1.<init>(ProcessInstancesControllerSpec.scala:108)
```

Line 108 is `"respond to the index Action" in new WithApplication {`

What could be the problem in this case?

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I changed line 108 to `"respond to the index Action" in new WithApplication(app.build) {`

now I got this error:

`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Fatal execution error, caused by play.api.libs.logback.LogbackLoggerConfigurator.configure(Lplay/api/Environment;Lplay/api/Configuration;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;)V`

**UPDATE:**

And If I do it this way:

```
val app = GuiceApplicationBuilder().overrides(bind[DeadboltHandler].to[DeadboltHandlerMock]).build
"respond to the index Action" in new WithApplication(app) {
```

I got this error:

`InvocationTargetException for 'main' in org.specs2.NotifierRunner: null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! Issue is a dependency problem of plugins.

If someone else has the same problem check which playframework version you use and which tests you import:

`scalatestplus-play` is important

You can find the version matrix here: 
https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play

Comment: ;) I have to still wait 17h bevore I can mark it as correct